# Tube size inquiry for my bike

Tags: repair

I’ve taken out the old tube which measures 700x35 45c but I could only find 700cx35 38. Will this fit ok? Many thanks

Comment: How did you "measure" the old tube.  (Hint: Check the side of the tire for measurements.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use an inner tube that's too narrow for the tyre?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4647/can-i-use-an-inner-tube-thats-too-narrow-for-the-tyre)

Comment: What do you mean by "700x35 45c"? You should measure the diameter of your tire instead of the tube. Then you go find a tube that has your tire width in that range. Lets say you have a 38c tire, you could use one that's meant for 35-42c.